# Add HtmlFormEntry and HtmlFormEntryUI dependency to POM.xml

Tags: maven, openmrs

I'm creating an OpenMRS module thats working with HtmlFormEntry. I need the HtmlFormEntry and HtmlFormEntryUI api packages to build mine.

That is, i get the errors `package org.openmrs.module.htmlformentry does not exist` and  `package org.openmrs.module.htmlformentryui does not exist` when compiling.

How can one define the dependency on the `htmlformentryui` and `htmlformentry` openmrs package and the  into a maven `POM.xml`?

Answer (score 1):

### HtmlFormEntry

Adding the dependency for `HtmlFormEntry` can be easily accomplished with the instructions in [this reference](https://wiki.openmrs.org/display/docs/How+to+Embed+HTML+Form+%28generated+by+HTML+Form+Entry+module%29+in+a+custom+module):

```
   <properties>
      ...
        <htmlformentryModuleVersion>3.1</htmlformentryModuleVersion>
      ...
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        ....
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openmrs.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>htmlformentry-api</artifactId>
            <version>${htmlformentryModuleVersion}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        ....
    </dependencies>
```

Note, i've updated the version number to `3.1`. It may have increased significantly by now. Check https://github.com/openmrs/openmrs-module-htmlformentry/releases to find the version you want to use.

### HtmlFormEntryUI

Based off of that we can extrapolate for `HtmlFormEntryUI`:

```
   <properties>
      ...
      <htmlformentryuiModuleVersion>1.6.0</htmlformentryuiModuleVersion>
      ...
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        ....
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openmrs.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>htmlformentryui-api</artifactId>
            <version>${htmlformentryuiModuleVersion}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        ....
    </dependencies>
```

Versions: https://github.com/openmrs/openmrs-module-htmlformentryui/releases